# Custom property loader with Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm using Spring Cloud Config in my spring-boot application and I need to write some custom code to handle properties to be read from my corporate password vault when property is flagged as such. I know spring cloud supports Hashicorp Vault, but that's not the one in case.

I don't want to hard-code specific properties to be retrieved from a different source, for example, I would have a properties file for application `app1` with profile `dev` with values:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

but for some other profiles such as `prod`, I would have:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=prod-user
spring.datasource.password=[[vault]]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

So I need the custom property vault to intercept the property loaded whenever it finds a returned value equals to `[[vault]]` (or some other type of flag), and query from the corporate vault instead. In this case, my custom property loader would find the value of property `spring.datasource.password` from the corporate password vault. All other properties would still be returned as-is from values loaded by standard spring cloud config client.

I would like to do that using annotated code only, no XML configuration.

Comment: Have you checked `EnvironmnentPostProcessor`?

Comment: Hi @StephaneNicoll,with EnvironmnentPostProcessor, I can't figure out how to scan loaded properties. `environment.getPropertySources().get("applicationConfigurationProperties")` doesn't let me iterate through properties, I can only query properties by key. There is a `getSource()` that returns an Object (that is actually ArrayList) with properties. It would need a cast that seems hacky. In addition, I couldn't find the underlying object of ConfigurableEnvironment that holds properties loaded from ConfigServer only the application.properties in the classpath. Further help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41463684/613628

Comment: Still a bit different though. In the answer provided, they are creating a new `PropertySource` with values from another custom source that is ready in advance. In my case, I need to scan the existing property sources (specially the one holding the values coming from the spring cloud config server), if the there is any property that contains the literal `[[vault]]` in the value, only then I will query the vault with the key I found. The vault I'm using won't send me everything available, I need to query by key.

Comment: I just realized you're the guy driving the demo at the Devoxx. Great presentation btw. :)

Comment: Thanks :) It is different but not so much. Put a debugger when your post processor is called and you'll see you'll have a list of property sources to inspect.

Comment: Yea, as I mentioned earlier, `environment.getPropertySources()` will give me this list, but `org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource` has no `keySet()` or `entrySet()` method. It only allows me to query properties if keys are known in advance. There is a `.getSource()` but this one returns generic `java.lang.Object` and I've inspected the underlying sources using the debugger and they all seem to have different implementations. That will need a bunch of cast which makes my feel I'm trying to follow a solution that is not mean for.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own [PropertySourceLocator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/config/PropertySourceLocator.java) and add entry to 
spring.factories in directory META-INF.

```
#spring.factories

org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=/
foo.bar.MyPropertySourceLocator
```

Then you can you can refer to keys in your corporate password vault like a normal properties in spring.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=prod-user
spring.datasource.password=${lodaded.password.from.corporate.vault}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Implementation by HasiCorp: [VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/blob/master/spring-cloud-vault-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java)

Answer (score 0):

While trying to solve the identical problem, I believe that I have come to work-around that may be acceptable.

Here is my solution below.

```
public class JBossVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
    Map<String, String> sensitiveProperties = propertySources.stream()
            .filter(propertySource -> propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
            .map(propertySource -> (EnumerablePropertySource<?>) propertySource)
            .map(propertySource -> {
                Map<String, String> vaultProperties = new HashMap<>();
                String[] propertyNames = propertySource.getPropertyNames();
                for (String propertyName : propertyNames) {
                    String propertyValue = propertySource.getProperty(propertyName).toString();
                    if (propertyValue.startsWith("VAULT::")) {
                        vaultProperties.put(propertyName, propertyValue);
                    }
                }
                return vaultProperties;
            })
            .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (m1, m2) -> {
                m1.putAll(m2);
                return m1;
            });

    Map<String, Object> vaultProperties = new HashMap<>();
    sensitiveProperties.keySet().stream()
            .forEach(key -> {
                vaultProperties.put(key, VaultReader.readAttributeValue(sensitiveProperties.get(key)));
            });

    propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("vaultProperties", vaultProperties));
}
```