# How to give @PropertyResource precedence over any other application.properties in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to add an external configuration property resource outside of the classpath. It should override any existing properties.

But the following does not work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("d:/app.properties")
public class MyClass extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyClass .class);
    }

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String myprop;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Sysout(myprop);
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
my.property=internal
```

d:/app.properties:

```
my.property=external
```

Result when I start the app: **internal**

Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `@PropertySource` handling has [a well defined precedence order](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config). You can customize the environment any way you want with an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

We explain that use case in a Devoxx presentation, please refer to [this section of the presentation](https://youtu.be/uof5h-j0IeE?t=1h18m20s) for more details. You can also [find the code sample online](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/hello-service-auto-configuration/blob/master/hello-app/src/main/java/com/example/hello/env/LocalSettingsEnvironmentPostProcessor.java).

In particular, you'll find that if you use `addFirst` your custom `PropertySource` will have precedence over everything. But you could also implement your `EnvironmentPostProcessor` so that command line arguments or system properties still override those values. I find that useful but your use case may differ.

Comment: Can I configure the order/precendence of the `@PropertySource` by annotation somehow=

Comment: So maybe I'm misusing the concept. My goal is as follows: usually I have a default `application.properties`, and profile-specific ones like `application-dev`,  `application-production`. Now what if someone want's to override a specific property in the production server? Someone who is not a developer and cannot rebuild the war. It's probably not a good idea to tell him the path to the exploded war and edit the application.properties there. I'd like to provide a simple file at a simple location for that kind of users.

Comment: The other answer has already a link to the doc that explains exactly that. Check `spring.config.location`. You can pass that as a command-line argument when starting the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Give two paths in `@PropertySource` annotation like:

`@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties",
        "<Path to your external application.properties>" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)`, now your external file will win if it has the same `key` for any property, thus overriding the `application.properties` in your resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is an order of precedence in loading external config -

- /config subdirectory of the current directory.
- The current directory
- classpath /config package
- The classpath root

So your current structure is finding the highest instance of the properties file

Try adding --spring.config.location to your external file, or place the external properties file in the directory you are starting spring-boot from

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Due to architecture, I can neither add an environment variable, nor can I place the external file into classpath. That's why I-'m asking... I know the directories above are supported by default. Anyways it should be possible to add a `PropertySource` as above. But id does not...

Comment: Thats tricky - can you start the application from d:/ so thats the current directory?

Comment: No I have to start the app as a `war` file, thus during `tomcat` application server startup.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by defining the `spring.config.location` property explicit during configuration of the app (as written I *cannot* add this as a jvm environment property on startup):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyClass extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyClass.class)
             .properties("spring.config.location=file:d/app.properties");
    }
}
```